# grouping by for a column on a table and counts KQL

Tags: kql

I have got a table within log analytics which  application exceptions `AppExceptions`  there are millions of records, I would like to  have a group by of the `InnermostMessage` column and a count to give me an idea of the number of records.

In plain t-SQL, I would do something like this.

```
select InnermostMessage, count(*) as Count
 from AppExceptions
   group by InnermostMessage
   where date between '' and ''
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a KQL query for the same

```html
AppExceptions
| where timestamp between(datetime('your_start_date') .. datetime('your_end_date'))
| summarize Count = count() by InnermostMessage
| order by Count desc
```

this gives a count of records for each unique value in the InnermostMessage column within the specified date range.